# Spring Integration outbound-channel-adapter destination-expression MQMDMessageContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using `Spring-Integration jms outbound-channel-adapter` that sends message to  dynamic queue. I use property `destination-expression="headers.DestinationQueueName"`. DestinationQueueName is set in code before outbound message written to `OUT_MSG` channel.

> 1. <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="msgWrtr"
> 2. connection-factory="MQConnectionFactory" channel="OUT_MSG"
> 3. destination-expression="headers.DestinationQueueName">
> 4. </int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>

How can I set these properties on queue: `MQMDMessageContext`, `MQMDReadEnabled` and `MQMDWriteEnabled`?

Comment: To Artem Bilan, I think you need queue name - can't have dynamic name. For my understanding - this is what you are suggesting, right? <bean id="outQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"><constructor-arg name="queueName" value="headers.DestinationQueueName" />

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of just `DestinationQueueName` String place to the headers the `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue` Object and with those options, of course?

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic destination name header expression is fine. Just configure a custom destination resolver to your JmsTemplate instance.

```
@Bean
public MQDestinationResolver mqDestinationResolver() {
    return new MQDestinationResolver();
}

public class MQDestinationResolver extends DynamicDestinationResolver implements CachingDestinationResolver {
        private final Map<String, Destination> destinationCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(16);
        private boolean cache = true;

        public void setCache(boolean cache) {
            this.cache = cache;
        }


    @Override
    public Destination resolveDestinationName(@Nullable Session session, String destinationName, boolean pubSubDomain)
            throws JMSException {
        Destination destination = this.destinationCache.get(destinationName);
        if (destination == null) {
            destination = super.resolveDestinationName(session, destinationName, pubSubDomain);
            MQDestination mqDestination = (MQDestination) destination;
            // Set IBM MQ specific destination properties
            mqDestination.setMQMDReadEnabled(true);
            mqDestination.setMQMDWriteEnabled(true);
            mqDestination.setMessageBodyStyle(WMQConstants.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_UNSPECIFIED);
            mqDestination.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_JMS_COMPLIANT);
            if (this.cache) {
                this.destinationCache.put(destinationName, destination);
            }
        }
        return destination;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeFromCache(String destinationName) {
        this.destinationCache.remove(destinationName);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearCache() {
        this.destinationCache.clear();
    }
}
```